# Is it possible to use paw and create a parsed loop?

Tags: paw-app

I'd like to parse the return of a request that has many bits of data. Can paw create an array and rerun requests? Example: My get returns 50 segments and I want to run a subsequent request against each of those 50 segments. Not the most efficient but it's how the system I'm working on exists.

Comment: Unfortunately, Paw isn't very useful for doing this. Paw is designed to accurately test one HTTP request, and isn't great to automate sending many requests. The best thing we recommend, is to use a Code Generator (at the bottom of the Paw window) to export a ready-to-use code snippet that you can use in a "for" loop in a language such as Python or Ruby. Hope it helps a little…